# Google Apps Script Call Function That Executes a Modal Dialog Box and then Another Function Once User Makes Selection

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a button linked on a Google Sheet that when the user clicks runs this function:

```
function ModalSelection(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main_gen');
  var cell = ss.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  if(cell == ''){
    checkWindow(); //It runs this function if `cell` is empty.
  //I would like to run another function here...anotherFunction()...but not until
  //the user has made their selections from the Modal Dialog box. 
  }
  else {send();} //send is not relevant to this question.
}
```

Here is the `checkWindow()` function:

```
function checkWindow(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = emailList(); //This is a string grabbed from another function.
  //Call the HTML file and set the width and height
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(result)
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(450);

  //Display the dialog
  var dialog = ui.showModalDialog(html, "Select your choices here.");
}
```

When the `checkWindow()` function is run and the user selects "Submit" it runs another short piece of code (see below) that inserts the users choices into a cell. I need to wait until this cell is no longer empty before proceeding to the next function.

```
function form_data(e){
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var value = [e.email];
  var val = value[0].toString();
  for(var i = 1; i<value.length; i++){val += ', ' + value[i];}
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 2).setValue(val);
  //I have tried adding the anotherFunction(); function right here, but the code breaks and the only error I see
  //in the console error log is "Uncaught". It gives me no additional details. 
}
```

**EDIT to include all HTML.**

The HTML code is below (EmailCheckBox.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id='myform'>
        <table border=0>

           %email

        </table>

    </form><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).form_data(document.getElementById('myform'))"/>
        <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()"/>
  </body>
```

The %email it refers to is this JS code:

```
function checkEmail(List){
  var output = '';
  for(var i=0; i<List.length; i++)
  {
    output += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="email" id="' + List[i] + '" value="' + List[i] + '"/>'+ List[i] + '</td></tr>'; 
  }
  var result = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('EmailCheckBox').getContent();
  result = result.replace('%email', output);
  Logger.log(result);

  return result;
}
</html>
```

**End EDIT**

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: In order to correctly understand about `I need to wait until this cell is no longer empty before proceeding to the next function.`, can you show us `html`?

Comment: @Tanaike I have edited the original question to add the html portion.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. In your script, if `document.getElementById('myform')` can send the correct value for `form_data(e)`, after the script of `form_data` was finished, `google.script.host.close` is run. How about this? If you want to use the put values just after `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 2).setValue(e)`, how about putting `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after that line? But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. So if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike...I have tried that to no avail. I will send you an example spreadsheet. Give me a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @Tanaike Here is the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16uWEgITpQt0nbjLV2IISWq6jkHYC5nafepth_kh3e8Q/edit#gid=0 Just run the `send()` function within the Send.gs file. You will see it briefly flashes the one pop up before immediately going to the next function.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the sample Spreadsheet. From the sample, I proposed the modification points as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to open the dialog of `sendCheck` after the process was finished at the dialog of `checkEmailWindow`.

For this, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `checkEmailWindow()` and `sendCheck()` are continuously run. By this, the dialog opened by `checkEmailWindow()` is overwritten by the dialog opened by `sendCheck()`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- In order to open the dialog of `sendCheck()` after the process was finished at the dialog of `checkEmailWindow`, I modified `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).form_data(document.getElementById('myform'))` as follows.

  - `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.run.sendCheck).form_data(document.getElementById('myform'))`
  - By this, the dialog of `sendCheck` is opened after the process was finished at the dialog of `checkEmailWindow`.

#### For `send()` in Google Apps Script side:

From:

```
if(bccSend == ''){
  checkEmailWindow();
  sendCheck();
}
```

To:

```
if(bccSend == ''){
  checkEmailWindow();
  // sendCheck();  // Removed
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

From:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).form_data(document.getElementById('myform'))"/>
```

To:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.run.sendCheck).form_data(document.getElementById('myform'))"/>
```

- `sendCheck` is run with `withSuccessHandler`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.